# Pandas GroupBy Datetime and Mean using Rolling

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, rolling-average

I want to calculate the mean of values rolling over Datetime index with a window of an P period of time centering on a Q period of time.

I have a dataset that have records in second:

```
Time                    Temperature     
2017-11-28 22:00:03     58.34
2017-11-28 22:00:05     57.54
2017-11-28 22:00:07     58.18
2017-11-28 22:00:09     58.18
2017-11-28 22:00:12     58.18
```

I would like to group meaning the values 2.5 minutes before and after 5 minutes frecuency and get something like this:

```
Time                    Temperature     
2017-11-28 22:05:00     mean(5 minutes before and after)
2017-11-28 22:10:00     mean(5 minutes before and after)
2017-11-28 22:15:00     mean(5 minutes before and after)
2017-11-28 22:20:00     mean(5 minutes before and after)
2017-11-28 22:25:00     mean(5 minutes before and after)
```

I'm trying with

```
hum_sta.set_index('Time').groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='5Min')).rolling("5min").mean()
```

But I'm not getting what I want, I just getting Multiindex Pandas Dataframe:

```
               Time  Time                Temperature    
2017-11-28 22:00:00  2017-11-28 22:00:03 NaN
                     2017-11-28 22:00:05 57.94
                     2017-11-28 22:00:07 57.86
                     2017-11-28 22:00:09 58.18
                     2017-11-28 22:00:12 58.18
```

Comment: What is the index? `Time`?

Comment: @roganjosh Yes!

Comment: Then you probably need to sort the df by `Time` before trying this

Comment: @roganjosh It's sorted!

Comment: Well clearly it isn't because you get `ValueError: index must be monotonic`. A side note, I can't help but read "!" as you shouting at me and I don't think you really intend that

Comment: @roganjosh Sorry about that. I sorted and i'm getting a new error.

Comment: It's fine, I just wanted to make sure you're aware how it might come across in text :) What is the new error? Please update the question

Comment: @roganjosh Updated. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think pandas right now can support all the operations needed for this. What about creating a new column, `rounded_time` which is (as you've guessed) the time rounded to 5 minutes, and then just `groupby("rounded_time").mean()` ?

Comment: @QusaiAlothman Sure, It might work, but I need the meaning of 2.5 minutes before and after each "rounded_time".